# JavaScript drag and drop photo resizer cropper

Tags: javascript, image, resize, photo, crop

I have an image of arbitrary size on the page. As an output I need an image of a fixed size, say *90x120px*. I would like the user to chose the area of the image by drag-and-dropping the big image behind the *90x120px* 'window'. The window would specify the resulting image. Something like this is implemented at [facebook image upload](http://www.facebook.com/editpicture.php).

I know how to deal with the image at backend as soon as I get the cropping coordinates, no problem with that. I guess I need to post the cropping coordinates in hidden form fields. User's drag-and-dropping action should make JavaScript populate the fields, right? I am new to JS, so a step-by-step guide would help a lot.

Comment: So how did you do the dragging with a big picture behind a small predefined box? Most projects seem to think I want to drag a crop-box inside the image, but I want the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Familiarize yourself with jQuery. It will save yourself time in any js/dhtml project
2. http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/drag.html http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/resize.html http://interface.eyecon.ro/download
3. ???
4. Profit

Answer (score 5):

For cropping, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html).